# Why don't I get any errors even when I am not implementing all the methods in the interface (Selenium Library)

Tags: java, selenium, interface

Here in this class, I haven't implemented all the methods in the Interface WebDriverListener which is from Selenium Library

```java
public class SeleniumListeners implements WebDriverListener{
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        System.out.println("In afterChangeValueOf");
    }
}
```

Comment: That interface defines default methods, which means they only need to be implemented if you want to do something other than its current implementation.

Comment: thanks @MarkRotteveel. I get that now.